# Using a Reference and Bibliography List in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to have a LaTeX document with a separate bibliography and reference list. They both have a relevant reference.bib and bibliography.bib. This is the current LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tabu}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Blah \cite{sharma2012sql}
\section{Conclusion} 
Blah 

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references,bibliography}
\section{Appendices}
Blah

\end{document}
```

This produces the output: [image]

This is almost what I want, except, I want a separate list for my bibliography, not for it to be join with my references (like seen below).
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since you are not using `biblatex`, but traditional BibTeX styles I have removed that tag.

Comment: You could have a look at the `bibtopic` or `splitbib` package. Or maybe even `bibunits` or `chapterbib`.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for pointing those out. I was trying to keep packages to a minimum. I also attempted to use `\bibliography{references} \bibliography{bibliography}` but this didn't yield anything.

Comment: As far as I know it is a feature that LaTeX normally only created one large bibliography from several `.bib` files. If you want to change that you will have to use an additional package (or switch to `biblatex` or the manual way of writing bibliographies).